# How to avoid the CRS Dialog when creating a vector layer memory?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I am trying to create a vector memory in a plugin. Basing on some examples,I was able to create a memory vector layer and to add it in QGis with : QgsMapLayer.instance().addMapLayer(myLayer,True)

But when the layer is added , QGis always displays the crs dialog to specify the crs of the layers

:[image: crs dialog]

I tried to specify myself the crs with :
layer.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReference(4326)) but it still shows me the crs dialog.

Do you have any ideas to how avoid this dialog ?

Answer (score 6):

In addition to changing the preferences in QGIS, another way to avoid the dialog is to specify the CRS when creating the memory layer (as opposed to changing it at a later step). This can be done using the URI string:

```
layer = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=EPSG:4326", "result", "memory")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

will create a memory layer using EPSG:4326 and add it to the registry without asking for the CRS to be specified, regardless of the QGIS preferences.

Answer (score 3):

I found a way in QGIS, in Setting>Options>CRS you can specify a default CRS, so the dialog will not appear. Hope it can help other peoples with same problems.

Answer (score 1):

This will prevent the popup from showing. 
The popup appears when you call `QgsVectorLayer()`. With Qt `blockSingals`, you can disable all signals to stop the signal calling the CRS dialog that is called when CRS is missing.

You can use the code below:

```
iface.mainWindow().blockSignals(True)

v_layer = QgsVectorLayer('Polygon?crs=EPSG:4326', 'layer_name', 'memory')

iface.mainWindow().blockSignals(False)
target_crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(
    4326, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.InternalCrsId
)
v_layer.setCrs(target_crs)
```