# Creating a memory layer without the CRS dialog in PyQGIS 3

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I am trying to create a memory layer:

```
tempLayer = QgsVectorLayer('LineString', 'my_temp_layer', 'memory')
```

But as soon as this line is excecuted (not when I add it to the map!) the CRS dialog pops up. How do I intercept that?

I know I can set the CRS, but that does not help, since the dialog pops up when the first line is executed...

```
tempLayer = QgsVectorLayer('LineString', 'trassen_tmp_bfp', 'memory')
tempLayer.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326))
```

Comment: Does it work if you specify the CRS while creating the memory layer? : https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/73981/67477

Comment: I create a layer like this:
 layer = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=EPSG:4326&index=yes","isoLayer","memory") ... Same problem occurs here as well.

Answer (score 3):

You have to include the crs in the `path` argument of the `QgsVectorLayer` constructor

```
tempLayer = QgsVectorLayer('LineString?crs=EPSG:4326', 'my_temp_layer', 'memory')
```

Alternatively, you can also set up QGis so that newly added layers use the project's CRS, or a default CRS (in *Settings/Options/CRS/Crs for new layers*)

[image: QGIS Options dialog]

You can also set those properties via the pyQGIS API

```
QSettings().setValue('/Projections/defaultBehavior', 'useProject')  # Use project's crs
```

or

```
QSettings().setValue('/Projections/defaultBehavior', 'useGlobal')  # Use default crs
QSettings().setValue('Projections/layerDefaultCrs', 'EPSG:4326')
```

Note that the default value for `'/Projections/defaultBehavior'` is `'prompt'`